# ReadFile From Certain Lines

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to check for this text
(Read)
And when it checks for it it reads the lines inside it
(Read)

Like this

```
TXT File:
(
Hi meh
dsa
(Read)
Test Code
Lines
(Read)
hello
sdas
)
```

Input: `File.ReadLines(CodeHere)`

Output:

```
Test Code
Lines
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine (**FSM**) with `2` state only: should you return current `line` or not:

```
  using System.IO;

  ...

  private static IEnumerable<string> MyRead(string fileName) {
    bool inRead = false;

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName)) 
      if (string.Equals(line, "(Read)")) 
        inRead = !inRead;
      else if (inRead)
        yield return line; 
  }
```

Then you can use

```
  foreach (string line in MyRead(@"c:\MyTest.txt"))
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```